# Nginx, Varnish 4.1 Backend fetch failed

Tags: nginx, varnish, joomla

I can access the site via https and the admin section., but can't access non https/guest or anything that should be cached.

```
varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T localhost:6082 debug.health
Connection failed (localhost:6082): (null)
```

Varnishlog

```
Begin          bereq 2 fetch
Timestamp      Start: 1489151629.565881 0.000000 0.000000
BereqMethod    GET
BereqURL       /
BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
BereqHeader    Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
BereqHeader    AcceptLanguage: enGB
BereqHeader    UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
BereqHeader    Host: www.website.com
BereqHeader    Cookie: __cfduid=d960b1ddcd82e149ba07d1d08b51868f01488714214; __atuvc=83%7C10; jbcookies=yes; onOffreadingmode=; nextPrevfont=Default; nextPrevfs=Medium; 2e6bfd3da2be20fdd818219a928632de=jh5ko0a723b6l4806mkj2tmjn5; 4dbbb894f976294264bd50dc4b48c008=48
BereqHeader    XForwardedFor: 23.227.207.10, 23.227.207.10
BereqHeader    AcceptEncoding: gzip
BereqHeader    XVarnish: 3
VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
VCL_return     fetch
FetchError     no backend connection
Timestamp      Beresp: 1489151629.566007 0.000126 0.000126
Timestamp      Error: 1489151629.566015 0.000134 0.000007
BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
BerespStatus   503
BerespReason   Service Unavailable
BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 13:13:49 GMT
BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
BerespHeader   ContentType: text/html; charset=utf8
BerespHeader   RetryAfter: 5
VCL_return     deliver
Storage        malloc Transient
ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
ObjStatus      503
ObjReason      Backend fetch failed
ObjHeader      Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 13:13:49 GMT
ObjHeader      Server: Varnish
ObjHeader      ContentType: text/html; charset=utf8
ObjHeader      RetryAfter: 5
Length         278
BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Netstart output

```
netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3123/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27943/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      807/php-fpm: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      807/php-fpm: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      858/memcached
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9003          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      807/php-fpm: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9004          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      807/php-fpm: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      807/php-fpm: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27943/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3123/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28446/pure-ftpd (SE
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      570/master
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      433/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      27943/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      28446/pure-ftpd (SE
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      570/master
```

Varnish
default.vcl

```
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

# Imports
import std;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1"; # don't change this if the web server is on the same machine
.port = "8080"; # replace XXXX with your web server's (internal) port, e.g. 8080
}

sub vcl_recv {

/*
# If we host multiple domains on a server, here you can list the domains you DO NOT want to cache
# The first check matches both naked & "www" subdomains. Use the second for non generic subdomains.
if (
    req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?(domain1.com|domain2.org|domain3.net)" ||
    req.http.host ~ "(subdomain.domain4.tld|othersubdomain.domain5.tld)"
) {
    return (pass);
}
*/

# Forward client's IP to the backend
if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.X-Real-IP) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Real-IP;
    } else if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}

# httpoxy
unset req.http.proxy;

# Normalize the query arguments
set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

# Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird.
if (
    req.method != "GET" &&
    req.method != "HEAD" &&
    req.method != "PUT" &&
    req.method != "POST" &&
    req.method != "TRACE" &&
    req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.method != "DELETE"
) {
    return (pipe);
}

# We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    return (pass);
}

# Don't cache HTTP authorization/authentication pages and pages with certain headers or cookies
if (
    req.http.Authorization ||
    req.http.Authenticate ||
    req.http.X-Logged-In == "True" ||
    req.http.Cookie ~ "userID" ||
    req.http.Cookie ~ "joomla_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" ||
    req.http.Cookie ~ "(wordpress_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"
) {
    #set req.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
    #set req.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
    #set req.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    return (pass);
}

# Exclude the following paths (e.g. backend admins, user pages or ad URLs that require tracking)
# In Joomla specifically, you are advised to create specific entry points (URLs) for users to
# interact with the site (either common user logins or even commenting), e.g. make a menu item
# to point to a user login page (e.g. /login), including all related functionality such as
# password reset, email reminder and so on.
if(
    req.url ~ "^/administrator" ||
    req.url ~ "^/component/banners" ||
    req.url ~ "^/component/socialconnect" ||
    req.url ~ "^/component/users" ||
    req.url ~ "^/contact" ||
    req.url ~ "^/connect" ||
    req.url ~ "^/wp-admin" ||
    req.url ~ "^/wp-login.php"
) {
    #set req.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
    #set req.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
    #set req.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    return (pass);
}

# Don't cache ajax requests
if(req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest" || req.url ~ "nocache") {
    #set req.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
    #set req.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
    #set req.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    return (pass);
}

# Check for the custom "X-Logged-In" header (used by K2 and other apps) to identify
# if the visitor is a guest, then unset any cookie (including session cookies) provided
# it's not a POST request.
if(req.http.X-Logged-In == "False" && req.method != "POST") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

# Properly handle different encoding types
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
  if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf)$") {
    # No point in compressing these
    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
  } elseif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
  } elseif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
  } else {
    # unknown algorithm (aka crappy browser)
    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
  }
}

# Cache files with these extensions
#if (req.url ~ "\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf)$") {
#    return (hash);
#}

# Remove all cookies for static files & deliver directly
if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (hash);
}

return (hash);

}

sub vcl_backend_response {

/*
# If we host multiple domains on a server, here you can list the domains you DO NOT want to cache
# The first check matches both naked & "www" subdomains. Use the second for non generic subdomains.
if (
    bereq.http.host ~ "(www\.)?(domain1.com|domain2.org|domain3.net)" ||
    bereq.http.host ~ "(subdomain.domain4.tld|othersubdomain.domain5.tld)"
) {
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
}
*/

# Don't cache 50x responses
if (
    beresp.status == 500 ||
    beresp.status == 502 ||
    beresp.status == 503 ||
    beresp.status == 504
) {
    return (abandon);
}

# Exclude the following paths (e.g. backend admins, user pages or ad URLs that require tracking)
# In Joomla specifically, you are advised to create specific entry points (URLs) for users to
# interact with the site (either common user logins or even commenting), e.g. make a menu item
# to point to a user login page (e.g. /login), including all related functionality such as
# password reset, email reminder and so on.
if(
    bereq.url ~ "^/administrator" ||
    bereq.url ~ "^/component/banners" ||
    bereq.url ~ "^/component/socialconnect" ||
    bereq.url ~ "^/component/users" ||
    bereq.url ~ "^/contact" ||
    bereq.url ~ "^/connect" ||
    bereq.url ~ "^/wp-admin" ||
    bereq.url ~ "^/wp-login.php"
) {
    #set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
    #set beresp.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
    #set beresp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
}

# Don't cache HTTP authorization/authentication pages and pages with certain headers or cookies
if (
    bereq.http.Authorization ||
    bereq.http.Authenticate ||
    bereq.http.X-Logged-In == "True" ||
    bereq.http.Cookie ~ "userID" ||
    bereq.http.Cookie ~ "joomla_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" ||
    bereq.http.Cookie ~ "(wordpress_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"
) {
    #set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
    #set beresp.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
    #set beresp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
}

# Don't cache ajax requests
if(beresp.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest" || bereq.url ~ "nocache") {
    #set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
    #set beresp.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
    #set beresp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
}

# Don't cache backend response to posted requests
if (bereq.method == "POST") {
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
}

# Ok, we're cool & ready to cache things
# so let's clean up some headers and cookies
# to maximize caching.

# Check for the custom "X-Logged-In" header to identify if the visitor is a guest,
# then unset any cookie (including session cookies) provided it's not a POST request.
if(bereq.method != "POST" && beresp.http.X-Logged-In == "False") {
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}

# Unset the "etag" header (suggested)
unset beresp.http.etag;

# Unset the "pragma" header
unset beresp.http.Pragma;

# Allow stale content, in case the backend goes down
set beresp.grace = 6h;

# This is how long Varnish will keep cached content
set beresp.ttl = 2m;

# Modify "expires" header - https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleSetExpires
#set beresp.http.Expires = "" + (now + beresp.ttl);

# If your backend server does not set the right caching headers for static assets,
# you can set them below (uncomment first and change 604800 - which 1 week - to whatever you
# want (in seconds)
#if (req.url ~ "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|webp|tiff|svg|svgz|pdf|mp3|flac|ogg|mid|midi|wav|mp4|webm|mkv|ogv|wmv|eot|otf|woff|ttf|rss|atom|zip|7z|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|tar|exe|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|rtf|odt|ods|odp)(\?[a-zA-Z0-9=]+)$") {
#    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public, max-age=604800";
#}

if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.do_stream = true;
}

# We have content to cache, but it's got no-cache or other Cache-Control values sent
# So let's reset it to our main caching time (2m as used in this example configuration)
# The additional parameters specified (stale-while-revalidate & stale-if-error) are used
# by modern browsers to better control caching. Set there to twice & five times your main
# cache time respectively.
# This final setting will normalize CMSs like Joomla which set max-age=0 even when
# Joomla's cache is enabled.
if (beresp.http.Cache-Control !~ "max-age" || beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "max-age=0") {
    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public, max-age=120, stale-while-revalidate=240, stale-if-error=480";
}

return (deliver);

}   

sub vcl_deliver {

/*
# Send a special header for excluded domains only
# The if statement can be identical to the ones in the vcl_recv() and vcl_fetch() functions above
if (
    req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?(domain1.com|domain2.org|domain3.net)" ||
    req.http.host ~ "(subdomain.domain4.tld|othersubdomain.domain5.tld)"
) {
    set resp.http.X-Domain-Status = "EXCLUDED";
}

# Enforce redirect to HTTPS for specified domains only
if (
    req.http.host ~ "(subdomain.domain4.tld|othersubdomain.domain5.tld)" &&
    req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https"
) {
    set resp.http.Location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    set resp.status = 302;
}
*/
# Send special headers that indicate the cache status of each web page
if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
} else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
}

return (deliver);

}
```

Nginx
nginxdomain.conf

```
# redirect from non-www to www 
# uncomment, save file and restart Nginx to enable
# if unsure use return 302 before using return 301
server {
        listen   8080;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;


# ngx_pagespeed & ngx_pagespeed handler
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeed.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedhandler.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedstatslog.conf;

#add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;  

# limit_conn limit_per_ip 16;
# ssi  on;

access_log /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/log/access.log main_ext buffer=256k flush=60m;
error_log /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/log/error.log;

include /usr/local/nginx/conf/autoprotect/domain.com/autoprotect-domain.com.conf;
root /home/nginx/domains/domain.com/public;
# uncomment cloudflare.conf include if using cloudflare for
# server and/or vhost site
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/cloudflare.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/503include-main.conf;

# prevent access to ./directories and files
# location ~ (?:^|/)\. {
# deny all;
#}

location / {
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/503include-only.conf;

# block common exploits, sql injections etc
# include /usr/local/nginx/conf/block.conf;

# Enables directory listings when index file not found
#autoindex  on;

# Shows file listing times as local time
#autoindex_localtime on;

# Enable Dynamic Proxy Cache
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;

# Enable for Joomla URL SEF usage
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

}

include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/vts_server.conf;
}
```

Varnish Params

```
# Varnish environment configuration description. This was derived from
# the old style sysconfig/defaults settings

# Set this to 1 to make systemd reload try to switch VCL without restart.
RELOAD_VCL=1

# Set WARMUP_TIME to force a delay in reload-vcl between vcl.load and vcl.use
# This is useful when backend probe definitions need some time before declaring
# configured backends healthy, to avoid routing traffic to a non-healthy backend.
#WARMUP_TIME=0

# Main configuration file. You probably want to change it.
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl

# Default address and port to bind to. Blank address means all IPv4
# and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify a host name, an IPv4 dotted
# quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
# VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=192.168.1.5
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80

# Admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082

# Shared secret file for admin interface
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret

# Backend storage specification, see Storage Types in the varnishd(5)
# man page for details.
VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,256M"

# User and group for the varnishd worker processes
VARNISH_USER=varnish
VARNISH_GROUP=varnish

# Other options, see the man page varnishd(1)
#DAEMON_OPTS="-p thread_pool_min=5 -p thread_pool_max=500 -p thread_pool_timeout=300"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your vcl is quite complicated.

What I see is :

- Varnish cannot reach the nginx backend (in the log `FetchError     no backend connection`)
- The backend host to which varnish is forwarding the request is `BereqHeader    Host: www.website.com`
- Varnish does not seem to forward requests to port `8080` the backend connection seems to be made to varnish itself
- Your nginx server does not listen to `www.website.com` host, only to `server_name domain.com www.domain.com;`

What I would try is

- Check that nginx listen to the host you are requesting
- Check your active configuration (using `varnishadm` then `backend.list` or `vcl.show`) to see if port 8080 is used

Comment: Its got worse, the server was rebooted and now will not start 
 
 Mar 10 19:08:30 server1 varnishd[2440]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 50404 127.0.0.1...-
          Varnish Cache CLI 1.0
                                        -----------------------------...
 Mar 10 19:08:47 server1 varnishd[2440]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 50404 127.0.0.1...t
 Mar 10 19:08:47 server1 varnishd[2440]: CLI telnet 127.0.0.1 50404 127.0.0.1...e

Comment: Mar 10 19:09:57 server1 varnishd[2440]: Manager got SIGINT
 Mar 10 19:09:57 server1 varnishd[2440]: Stopping Child
 Mar 10 19:09:57 server1 systemd[1]: Stopping Varnish Cache, a high-performa.....
 Mar 10 19:09:58 server1 varnishd[2440]: Child (2441) died signal=15
 Mar 10 19:09:58 server1 systemd[1]: Stopped Varnish Cache, a high-performan...r.
 Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
 [19:15][root@server1 ~]# varnishadm

Comment: [19:15][root@server1 ~]# varnishadm 
 Abandoned VSM file (Varnish not running?) /var/lib/varnish/server1/_.vsm

Comment: Varnish that is, Nginx is serving on 8080

Comment: your varnish is not running so you cannot check its current vcl. Can you start varnish again and if it fails look at the systemd logs to know why it cannot start?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `default.vcl` and the error I conclude that you are configuring the **default backend** but not using it.

To do that you can add the line below to the beginning of `vcl_recv` so it looks like this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.backend_hint = default;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi alejdg, I have added the line and restarted varnish, same issue.